# Show TIME instead of DATE in Timeline Highcharts

Tags: datetime, highcharts, timeline

Currently my timeline highcharts look like this.[image]

I hope to change the date there to current time. Is it possible to make it?

[Here my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/date-to-time-timeline-highchart-mxboi?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the date format in dataLabels setting to show the time instead of date like this

```
   dataLabels: {
     allowOverlap: false,
     format:
       '<span style="color:{point.color}">● </span><span style="font- 
       weight: bold;" > ' +
       "{point.x:%H:%M:%S}</span><br/>{point.label}"
   }
```

DateFormat reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Time#dateFormat